# How can I keep the same bar width with ggbarplot when using colour = "" and position = position_dodge()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, column-width, position-dodge

I have made a bar plot using ggplot. The middle bar splits into two when I specify colour = "" based on the structure of my treatments. I then use position = position_dodge(0.8) to have the bars next to each other rather than stacked. However, after I specify position = position_dodge(0.8) the bars reduce in size even thought I specify the width=0.7. I want all the bars to have equal size.

This is the relevant code:

```
ggbarplot(dataset, x = "combi", y = "c.ug.positive.container.whole", 
          color = "label.plant", 
          add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
          position = position_dodge(0.8),
          width=0.7, size =1, fatten=1)
```

[and the figure produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAg47.png)

I am basically trying to get the two middle bars to have the same width as the other two on the left and right.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try with `position_dodge(0.8, preserve = "single")`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.